# output of citing "incollection"

Tags: bibtex, citing

I copied the following BibTeX from MathSciNet

```
@incollection {MR2408155,
AUTHOR = {Noohi, Behrang},
TITLE = {Lectures on derived and triangulated categories},
BOOKTITLE = {An invitation to noncommutative geometry},
PAGES = {383--418},
PUBLISHER = {World Sci. Publ., Hackensack, NJ},
YEAR = {2008},
MRCLASS = {18E30 (18E10)},
MRNUMBER = {2408155},
MRREVIEWER = {Friedrich W. Bauer},
DOI = {10.1142/9789812814333_0006},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812814333_0006},}
```

This is giving the following output in the pdf

Behrang Noohi. Lectures on derived and triangulated categories. **In An** invitation to noncommutative
geometry, pages 383–418. World Sci. Publ., Hackensack, NJ, 2008.

I want to get

Behrang Noohi. Lectures on derived and triangulated categories. **In : An** invitation to noncommutative
geometry, pages 383–418. World Sci. Publ., Hackensack, NJ, 2008.

I have tried to insert semicolon in "BOOKTITLE", but, it is not looking nice.

Is there a standard bibtex format to cite apart from what I copied from Mathscinet which would give "In : An" as outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For entries of type `@incollection`, it is common practice -- though, presumably, not an absolute requirement -- to mention the editor(s) of the collection of papers. Unfortunately, the bib entry you obtained from MathSciNet is missing the field

```
editor = {Masoud Khalkhali and Matilde Marcolli},
```

If you backfill this piece of information, and if you employ a bibliography style such as `plainnat`, you'd get the following output:

[image]

Observe that once you provide the `editor` field, there's no real need to append a colon after the word "In".

Moral of the story? Don't blindly trust the information obtained from online sources.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% create a bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@incollection{MR2408155,
    AUTHOR    = {Noohi, Behrang},
    TITLE     = {Lectures on derived and triangulated categories},
    editor    = {Masoud Khalkhali and Matilde Marcolli}, 
    BOOKTITLE = {An Invitation to Noncommutative Geometry},
    PAGES     = {383--418},
    PUBLISHER = {World Sci.\ Publ.},
    address   = {Hackensack NJ},
    YEAR      = {2008},
    MRCLASS   = {18E30 (18E10)},
    MRNUMBER  = {2408155},
    MRREVIEWER= {Friedrich W. Bauer},
    xDOI      = {10.1142/9789812814333_0006},
    URL       = {https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812814333_0006},
    isbn      = {978-9812706164},
}
\end{filecontents}
%% Aside: There's no real need to provide both 'url' and 'doi' fields.
%% However, providing the 'isbn' field would be a nice touch.

\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bibliography style

\usepackage{xurl} % for handling long URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address a point raised by the OP in a follow-up comment. How to change the prefix particle from "In" to "In:" depends mainly on the bibliography style that's in use. The OP hasn't indicated which bibliography style is in use. Should it be the `plainnat` style, I suggest the OP proceed as follows:

- Locate the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the file, say, `plainnat_in_colon.bst`.
- Open the file `plainnat_in_colon.bst` in an editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Replace all eight [8!] instances of `"In`  with `"In:` .
- Save the bst file in the directory that contains your main tex file.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat_in_colon}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. "In Masoud Khalkhali and Matilde Marcolli, editors, An invitation to Noncommutative geometry" does not look like the standard citation.. I do not remember seeing it anywhere... Can you please give some reference where one can find such citation output.. I am sorry if it sounds rude but I do not like it very much :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - not sure I understand what you’re objecting to. E.g,. if you follow the entry’s URL, you’ll see an image of the front page of the book, and right on the front page you’ll find the names of the book’s two editors. I guess I don’t understand your aversion to providing an `editor` field even though the entry type `@incollection` provides for exactly this field. Please elaborate.

Comment: I have no issue with providing editors details. I was thinking grammatically "In Masoud Khalkhali and Matilde Marcolli, editors, An invitation to Noncommutative geometry" does not sound nice... English is not my first language so I am not familiar with this kind of phrase...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - I respectfully disagree with the claim that "In ..." doesn't sound nice. Please see the addendum I just posted for a way to insert a colon after `In` if you simply cannot stand the situation without a colon after "In".

Comment: Sorry.. those are some drawbacks of not knowing the language well :)... Apart from that, I learned that it is good to add details of editors and also the ISBN... Many thanks..